# How do I make this else if statement into a recursive statement?

Tags: if-statement, recursion

I am trying to make this code recursive. It is supposed to print our "R" if int x is odd and "L" if int x is even.

```
public String findRL(int x){
    s="";
    while (x > 1){
        if (x%2 ==0){
            s = "L" + s;
        }
        else{
           s = "R" + s;
           x = x/2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking for. The method itself **prints** nothing, but returns a String? So, start by clarifying your requirements, and then tell us where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to make this code recursive

First step should be trying to make the code work.  It's declared to return `String` but it never returns `s`.  Also, it readily goes into an infinite loop once `x` becomes even.  So let's replace it with this similar function:

```
public String findRL(int x) {
    String s = "";

    while (x > 1) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            s += "L";
        } else {
            s += "R";
        }
        x /= 2;
    }

    return s;
}
```

This might not be equivalent to what you were trying to do, but should be good enough to see how we might convert your actual code to a recursive function:

```
public String findRL(int x) {
    String s = "";

    if (x > 1) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            s = "L";
        } else {
            s = "R";
        }

        s += findRL(x / 2);
    }

    return s;
}
```

We don't change the `if ... else` statement into recursion but rather the `while` loop as *recursion* typically uses an *implicit* loop in place of an *explicit* loop in *interation*.